# 404 error in Flask tutorial

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I just started using the Flask tutorial :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    return 'User %s' % (username)
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

I was wondering what is wrong here, the tutorial does not say anything straight about this error.

Comment: What URL are you accessing? It would obviously need to match a route defined in your application.

Comment: well to be honest, I have no more clue other than this, I was running this in python interpreter : $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: Ok, I assume you're accessing 127.0.0.1:5000 in the browser. This is calling the route "/" which isn't defined in your application. You've only defined "/user/<username>"

Comment: hmm, so if I call route('/'), and keep the rest untouched, it gives me error:TypeError: show_user_profile() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)...I was wondering how to call that route('/user/<username>') ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your virtual environment.

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

**UPDATED**
Try this on your python shell:

```
>>> from flask import Flask, url_for
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> @app.route('/')
... def index(): pass
...
>>> @app.route('/user/<username>')
... def profile(username): pass
...
>>> with app.test_request_context():
...  print url_for('index')
...  print url_for('profile', username='John Doe')
...
/
/user/John%20Doe
```

Your url is missing the argument `<username>`.

Comment: I am alreday inside the virtual environment. My code works fine till I call  @app.route('/') , the server error occurs when I call @app.route ('/something_else')

Comment: @bhjghjh add some more code to the question from your routes plus which is the url that leads to the error?

Answer (score 0):

As @MattHealy pointed out you've only got one route, `/user/<username>`. `<username>` is part of a "dynamic url". It's explained right in the tutorial: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules.

That means that portion of the URL gets passed into your view function as an argument. Then within your view function you can use as you would any other string in Python. So you need to send a request to something like: *http://localhost:5000/user/yourusername*

Comment: What happens when the correct url is used, but no value for <username> in the url.
ie:  http://localhost:5000/user/yourusername
ie valid
 http://localhost:5000/user/
returns 404 error.


I tried 
if username == None:
   do blah
else:
   do the normal stuff would do if username was non-null value

also tried creating a duplicate method with no args. ie
def show_user_profile():
    return 'User name required"

both of these failed.

Comment: both of these failed because the route above does not cover this combination.  

@app.route('/user/')
def hello_user_noname():
    do blah.